# automatic end useless processes

Tags: windows-7, windows, task-manager, tasks

in WIN 7 if you open windows with administrator username, you will have lots and lots of procceses active.

But if I login with guest I will have 70% less processes, but still enough for what I need. But i just dont have any privileges.

Is there a program that automatically ends up all  non useful tasks?

I have tuneup, it is great but doesnt solve this.

Comment: How  would a program automatically decide which task is useless to you?

Comment: Are you sure that there are fewer processes running? There may be just as many present, but they are hidden from the guest user with lower privileges.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be such large difference, click the **Show processes for all users** button and log in as an administrator in the UAC prompt that shows. You can automatically decide to kill stuff, for example, by using scripts that run [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683); but we can't help you in more detail unless you specify how it should decide...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check which applications are starting up automatically and disable any that you don't want.

An easy way to modify that list, at least for testing, is to press Start and type in `msconfig` and hit `ENTER`.  That allows you to turn off programs that are scheduled to run on startup.

Also, if you have sufficient RAM available, it's not really a big concern if applications are running.  You should start to worry if you'd hitting > 75% memory usage.  To check this, go to the Task Manager (right-click the Start Menu) and go to the Performance tab.  Check the `Physical Memory` section and see if the `Available` amount is > 25% of the `Total` amount (do NOT look at the `Free` amount, that's including file cache, which is irrelevant in this context).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Msconfig in Windows to trim down startup programs and services.

First use Msconfig to take some programs out of the startup list

http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html

Then go to the Services tab of Msconfig and check the "hide all Microsoft Services" box

Now you will see all the services installed by 3rd party software, you can Google each one and make your own determination if you should disable it, disabling all Non Microsoft services is ok, but some programs may depend on them to start and run, if you do not use these related softwares then disable that associated service.

Reboot the PC

There will be little difference between processes for a regular account or a Guest account, most are hidden when in the guest account for security reasons, but they are still running.

.